# How to print out text as HTML in Java

Tags: java, jboss

My apologies in advance: despite MUCH research, I'm not even sure how to construct the following question:

I'm working with Java/JBoss, and I've set up a class to read in an XML file, parse through it, and take the various nodeValues to build a string of HTML. Now all I need to do is print/insert that HTML into the DOM.

I was trying:

```
<div id='wrapper'>#{MyClass.methodThatReturnsAnHTMLString()}</div>
```

But the HTML simply appeared as escaped text on screen with source code as follows:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    &lt;div class='item'&gt;content&lt;/div&gt;
</div>
```

Thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this.  Instead, learn how to put data only into the HttpRequest object, and to access these in your JSP (or templates, or whatever) pages.  Keep your presentation code out of your business logic.

Comment: I think it adds escaping by default (avoiding XSS)

This is a good resource on the subject 

http://pukkaone.github.com/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html

Comment: you might want to upvote and accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the

```
>#{MyClass.methodThatReturnsAnHTMLString()}
```

with

```
<c:out value="${MyClass.methodThatReturnsAnHTMLString}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use JSTl to print the out put like :

```
<c:out value="${body.content}" />
```

It basically escape HTML/XML content.

If you use script-let then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html).

**EDIT**

The org.apache.commons.lang package provides a class called `StringEscapeUtils` that has methods that help to escape and unescape Strings for Java, Java Script, HTML, XML, and SQL. Given your scenario, I think this might prove useful to you. :-)

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to answer like this. If you are linking in your answer please explain what you are linking to (name/description of document), and include a summary or extract showing why it might be useful.

Comment: Yeah, i had come across this, but I can't seem to import it. (No .lang from the .commons).

Comment: Did you download the jar correctly? And import the jars into your IDE before trying to import it into the project?